# Is there a way to use await keyword inside render in React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, substrate

I am trying to use the Substrate UI to display the functionalities that are available in my run-time module. The code is written in React. I am trying to create a component that will help me track all the previous states of a structure.

The `runtime.template.assets(i)` call takes a hex value `i` as input and returns a structure `kitty` which has a key `parent_hash`(having a hex value). I want the `while` loop to execute till I have reached a special hex value which in this case is `"0x11da6d1f761ddf9bdb4c9d6e5303ebd41f61858d0a5647a1a7bfe089bf921be9"` which I have converted to `String` to achieve the termination condition.

Please ignore the `<KittyShrieks>` tag because it is something that I am using to display some values in the UI. Basically I am unable to do this inside the while loop

```
var kitty = await runtime.template.kitties(i);
.
.
i = kitty.parent_hash;
```

The required code

```
export class TrackCards extends ReactiveComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(['hash'])

    }


    unreadyRender() {
        return <span>Nothing to track</span>
    }
    async readyRender() {
      let kitties = [];
        var i = this.state.hash;
        var root_hash = "0x11da6d1f761ddf9bdb4c9d6e5303ebd41f61858d0a5647a1a7bfe089bf921be9";
        var root = "17,218,109,31,118,29,223,155,219,76,157,110,83,3,235,212,31,97,133,141,10,86,71,161,167,191,224,137,191,146,27,233";
        var iter = 0;
        var a;

        while ((root != i.toString())  {


          var kitty = await runtime.template.kitties(i);
          kitties.push(
              <div className="column" key={i}>

                  <KittyShrieks
                  owner_count = {runtime.template.kittyHistoryCount(i)}
                  hash_original = {this.state.hash}
                  />
              </div>
          );
          i = kitty.parent_hash;
        }
        return <div className="ui stackable six column grid">{kitties}</div>;
    }
}
```

I don't think using async render is a valid thing, but I am doing that because I seem to have no choice but to use the `await keyword`. So, the problem is that the UI doesnot load and I get the following error:

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

The UI loads fine if I remove `async` keyword, `var kitty = await runtime.template.kitties(i);` statement and insert a `break` statement at the end of the loop. Therefore, disallowing me to iterate through the loop.

I am kind of new to React and even Javascript in general. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: render should be pure, instantiate async tasks in ```componentDidMount```

Comment: You can also use new useEffect hook for this, make async code inside the hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A component always needs to be able to render something (or `null`). Here, effectively you are asking React to render a `promise`, hence your error.

You should extract this logic into the `componentDidMount()` life cycle. Taking your code as an example, it could look something like this:

```
export class TrackCards extends ReactiveComponent {
  constructor(props) {
      super(['hash'])

      this.state = {
        kitties: []
      }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const kitties = [];
    var i = this.state.hash;
    var root_hash = "0x11da6d1f761ddf9bdb4c9d6e5303ebd41f61858d0a5647a1a7bfe089bf921be9";
    var root = "17,218,109,31,118,29,223,155,219,76,157,110,83,3,235,212,31,97,133,141,10,86,71,161,167,191,224,137,191,146,27,233";
    var iter = 0;
    var a;

    while (root != i.toString())  {
      var kitty = await runtime.template.kitties(i);
      kitties.push(
          <div className="column" key={i}>
              <KittyShrieks
              owner_count = {runtime.template.kittyHistoryCount(i)}
              hash_original = {this.state.hash}
              />
          </div>
      );
      i = kitty.parent_hash;
    }
    this.setState(
      kitties
    );
  }

  render () {
    const { kitties } = this.state;
    return (
      kitties.length 
        ? <div className="ui stackable six column grid">{kitties}</div>
        : <span>Nothing to track</span>
    )
  }
}
```

We are initially returning `<span>Nothing to track</span>`, while you are waiting for `kitties` to complete.

Comment: I am able to iterate through the loop now using your solution. But the `kitties` list gets updated in the `componentDidMount()` but the the same doesn't get reflected in the `render` (It shows as empty). The component displays `"Nothing to track"`.